# apprequest box appears in the middle of app (only in IE)

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, apprequests

I have an issue with IE. When I call the apprequest the box appears at the middle of the app. and since the app is pretty big (2000px) the user cant say if the box has appears or not (the only way to check it is to scroll down, but if its the first time of the user he will not understand)

Im not sure if you had already this problem. I have not a clue where the problem could be. And the worst thing is that in chrome and ff is working perfectly. This thing is making me crazy.

The only bug I get is some bug from jquery-ui but I deactivated it and the problem with the apprequest box stills there. Maybe is there a way to determine the position of the apprequest-box?

Thanks for the help!